# Fuzzy duplicates within an index range

Tags: python, algorithm

The following is an interview question that a friend was asked. We're both stumped. The statement is as follows:

> Consider an unsorted list of integers, `A`. Suppose `A` has size `n`. Suppose, further, that the element at index `i` has value `x`. We define two terms:
>
> - `A` has "a duplicate in index range `k`" if the value `x` is at any of `A[i-k], A[i-k+1],...,A[i-1],A[i+1],...,A[i+k]` (i.e. `k` is the radius of the search across indicies)
> - `A` has "a duplicate in value range `d`" if any element of `A` lies in the range `x-d, x-d+1,...,x,x+1,...,x+d` (i.e. `d` is the radius of the search across values)
>
> In O(n) time and O(k) space, we want to know:
>
> 1. Does `A` have a duplicate in index range `k`?
> 2. Does `A` have a duplicate in index range `k` AND value range `d`?

The first one is easy: we walk from index `0` to `n-1` and keep a set of the past `k` numbers we've seen. If our current number is already in the set before we add it, we have a duplicate. Otherwise we don't, and we remove the oldest element in the set to make room for the new one.

The second one, I have no idea. I can think of a solution in O(nd) time and O(k) space: keep the same set as we did for the first problem, but, when we hit `x`, check for every number between `x-d` and `x+d`.  But I can't imagine what a solution that doesn't have `d` in either the space or time complexity would look like. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the second part by an extension of your first method.

Instead of storing the raw value in the set, instead use a dictionary and store the value divided by d+1 (mapping to the actual value).

The main point is that we can be sure that no 2 values can lie in the same bin (or they are closer than d apart).

Now when you scan through, you need to check for possible collisions in the bin plus the two neighbouring bins.

So this is O(3n) = O(n) operations and O(k) space.

### Example Python Code

```
def check_for_duplicate(A,d,k):
    D = {} # Stores the previous 2k entries 
    for i,a in enumerate(A):
        b = a // (d+1)
        for delta in [-1,0,1]:
            if b+delta in D and abs(D[b+delta] - a) <= d:
                return True
        old = i - 2 * k
        if old >= 0:
            del D[ A[old] // (d+1) ]
        D[b] = a
    return False

print check_for_duplicate(A=[8,14],d=5,k=2)
```

Comment: Can you show examples of what you mean? Lets say d=5 , and two numbers in the list 8 and 14 , it should say 8 and 14 are not fuzzy duplicate of each other.

Comment: 8/(5+1)=1, 14/(5+1)=2 so these will be stored in different bins.  When we check for values in neighbouring bins we double check the actual values to see if there is an overlap (in this case there is not).  This is why the values are stored in a dictionary instead of a simple set.

Comment: then it again becomes a O(nd) ? Because its possible that a bin has `d` elements?

Comment: No, because the main point is that each bin can have at most 1 element (or we can terminate early because we have found a duplicate) - I've added some example code that may make things clearer...

Comment: You don't need to hold 2k elements even though there are 2k elements in the range, since you're only checking the previous k.
arr = [8, 1, 15, 11, 1], k = 2, d = 0 should return False since the two 1s are a distance of 3 apart

Answer (score 1):

So it occurs to me, you could just do

```
part1 = false;
part2 = false;
for (index = i - k; index <= i + k, index++) {
  diff = ABS(A[index] - x);
  if (diff == 0) { part1 = true; }
  if (diff < d) { part2 = true; }
}
```

(not in python, but the algorithm seems sufficient) Let me know if I'm totally missing the point, it's late here.

Comment: thats an `O(nk)` algorithm.

Comment: I see now that I've misunderstood the question. I read the last lines as more of "for a particular index of A: . . ."